# How do I update a Fargate profile with eksctl?

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, eksctl

I created an AWS EKS Fargate cluster with the following Fargate profile

```
fargateProfiles:
  - name: fp-fluxcd
    selectors:
      - namespace: fluxcd
```

How do I either add (or change) the namespace so it looks like this?

```
fargateProfiles:
  - name: fp-fluxcd
    selectors:
      - namespace: fluxcd
      - namespace: flux-system
```

I updated the config file and tried `eksctl upgrade -f my-cluster.yml` to no avail.

I guess another way to skin the cat is to add the fargate nodes to a namespace? How to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can see in the [AWS Fargate profile](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/fargate-profile.html) documentation:

> Fargate profiles are immutable. However, you can create a new updated profile to replace an existing profile and then delete the original after the updated profile has finished creating.

Fargate profiles are immutable by design, so there is no `update` command.
In my opinion you should use `eksctl create fargateprofile` and `eksctl delete fargateprofile` commands instead.

Additionally you can find similar discussion [here](https://github.com/weaveworks/eksctl/issues/2399).

Comment: Once the fargateprofile was created and the previous one deleted, I had to delete all the pods to ensure that the old fargate nodes were replaced by the newer ones.